# Issue In Removing Double Or More Slashes From URL By .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, slash

I am using the following htaccess rul to remove double or more slashes from web urls:

```
#remove double/more slashes in url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

This is working fine for slashes occured in the middle of uris, such as, If use url:

```
http://demo.codesamplez.com/html5//audio
```

Its being redirected to proper single slahs url:

http://demo.codesamplez.com/html5/audio

But if the url contains double slashes in the beginning, JUST AFTER the domain name, then there its not working, example:

```
http://demo.codesamplez.com//html5/audio
```

its not being redirected.

How I can fix the above rule to work for this type of urls as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Give it a try with:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

It should redirect to a single slash at the end of the domain.
And an improvement on yours:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Based off your answer, to replace multiple hyphens, I did: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)--(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1-%2 [R=301,L]   --works, thanks

Comment: @Marcel It doesn't seem to keep the query params in the url.

Comment: The first solution ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} works with N number of slashes without fail. However improvment suggested fails depending on number of slashes in the URL. Hence improvment is not useful instead buggy.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the following rules work perfectly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /

    # rule 1: remove multiple leading slashes (directly after the TLD)
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/{2,}
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]

    # rule 2: remove multiple slashes in the requested path
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The idea is heavily based on Marcels answer (thanks!), but this one is a bit more lightweight and includes the `RewriteBase`, which may be helpful if you work with specific subdirectory structures. Additionally, Marcels answer lacks explanation, which I wanted to fix:

Rule 1: `{THE_REQUEST}` contains something like `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1` (see [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)). Hence, if we match the first whitespace (`\s`) followed by multiple slashes (`/{2,}`), we can access the correct URL without the leading double slash via `$1`.

Rule 2: The regular expression `^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$` splits the request URI on multiple slashes. `%1/%2` then combines the two splitted strings again, but with only one slash at this time.

Comment: but assume the following: `localhost/hey/thanks/a/lot//////////` is executed, the result is `localhost/hey/thanks/a/lot/` i want to remove the final slash

Comment: @AlanDeep This is a different issue with a different [solution](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#remove-trailing-slash).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be able to handle more complex cases with multiple occurrences of multiple slashes in the URL - e.g. `///some//more///complicated///path//`

Answer (score 8):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933916/1565283)
link, following code should take care of extra slashes(anywhere) in URL.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: The regex `//` will create a redirect loop (when compared against `THE_REQUEST`) if multiple slashes occur anywhere in the _query string_. The linked answer has been updated to use `\s[^?]*//` - which ensures multiple slashes are only matched in the URL-path, not the query string (if present).

Answer (score 3):

To prevent long repetition of characters in your url such as:

```
http://demo.codesamplez.com/html5///////////////////////////////////////////audio
```

you can do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]
```

It should works with :

```
http://demo.codesamplez.com//html5/audio
```

see also: [.htaccess - how to remove repeated characters from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439437/htaccess-how-to-remove-repeated-characters-from-url/19472215#19472215)

Comment: will not work if url is domain.com// - the redirected url will be the same!

Comment: This answer is good enough and works with the given example. In your case use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)?$` to declare as optional the last group of characters. Next time please ask before voting down.

Answer (score 2):

The situation is simple to resolve using a tasty slice of .htaccess. All you need to do is copy the following code and your site’s root `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
# Rule 1: remove multiple leading slashes (directly after the TLD)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/{2,}
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]
# Rule 2: remove multiple slashes in the requested path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Rule 1:** `{THE_REQUEST}` contains something like `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`

Hence, if we match the first whitespace `(\s)` followed by multiple slashes `(/{2,})`, we can access the correct URL without the leading double slash via `$1`.

**Rule 2:** The regular expression `^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$` splits the request URI on multiple slashes. `%1/%2` then combines the two splitted strings again, but with only one slash at this time.

**So for example, this directive will redirect as follows:**

https://www.meysmahdavi.com// redirects to https://www.meysmahdavi.com/
https://www.meysmahdavi.com//blog-post/ redirects to https://www.meysmahdavi.com/blog-post/
https://www.meysmahdavi.com//path/directory/ redirects to https://www.meysmahdavi.com/path/directory/

So basically it removes the double slashes from any URL.

Source From: https://www.meysmahdavi.com/

Comment: This is great! Had stumped me for a while. This addressed my issue where only one set of multiple slashes was being address, e.g.: example.com///page-1///page-2

Answer (score 0):

Just put the below code to your .htaccess file.
it will remove multiple slash from anywhere . at the end of url and in from middle of url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /`enter code here`
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=302,L,NE]
#Remove slash anywhere from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
# Rule 1: remove multiple leading slashes (directly after the TLD)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/{2,}
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]
# Rule 2: remove multiple slashes in the requested path`enter code here`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation that I have found works better when you have one .htaccess file and many subdirectories:

```
# Remove multiple slashes anywhere in url

# rule 1: Remove multiple leading slashes directly after the domain name
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/{2,}
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=301,L]
 
# rule 2: Remove multiple slashes anywhere in the rest of the path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```