# removing multiple groups of slashes everywhere in URL in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I currently have a website where guests are able to access each url with any number of slashes to separate folder names. For example, if a URL is supposed to be:

```
http://example.com/one/two/three/four
```

Then users could access the same page via any of the following:

```
http://example.com/one//two///three////four/////
http://example.com/one/two////three/four/////
http://example.com///one///////////two////three/four/
http://example.com///////////one///////////two/three/four
```

However, I want the above example urls to only redirect users to this URL:

```
http://example.com/one/two/three/four
```

This is my .htaccess file to attempt to stop the enormous slashes:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/+(.*)/+$
RewriteRule .* /%1 [R=301,L]
```

The third line successfully stops trailing slashes on long URLs. The 4th and 5th lines are my attempt to stop trailing slashes right after the domain name, but that was unsuccessful.

The reason why I ask this question is because I don't want google to catch me for duplicate content and with adsense active on the site, google will likely scan all the URLs that I access.

Is there a RewriteCond/RewriteRule combo I can use to strip the middle slashes or is it more involved?

Answer (score 21):

You can use this rule for removing multiple slashes anywhere in URL **except query string**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: e.g. `https://localhost///////////one///////////two//////////three/four///////` will become `https://localhost/one/two/three/four/` in a single redirect.

Comment: Definitely works, @Mike you should accept this answer. Thanks anubhava.

Comment: It will work with any number of slashes more than one

Comment: Is this an undocumented behavior? Because Apache HTTP Server documentation states: `$0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.` It does not mention that it will auto squeeze all `//` into single `/`.

Comment: @MarisB. It is not always easy to find documentation reference for all the features. Documentation is scattered in multiple places but this is an established fact that multiple `//` get converted to single `/` in the pattern of `RewriteRule`

Comment: @MarisB. It's not the `$0` backreference itself that reduces multiple slashes. As you state, `$0` simply contains the whole string matched by the pattern. In a _directory_ (or `.htaccess`) context, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the URL-path _after_ it has been mapped to the filesystem. It is the process of mapping the request to the filesystem that reduces multiple slashes. Conversely, the same directive does not work if used in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context - which is processed _before_ the request is mapped to the filesystem (when multiple slashes have not been reduced).

Comment: @anubhava, can you please explain why 302 and not 301 ? Who would want to remove slashes just temporary ?

Comment: 302 is only for testing so that you don't have to clear browser cache while testing. Once tested it should be `301` only.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```