# Urls redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My urls have http://test.com//123.html

Notice it has // from a 3rd party which is not under my control so I want to catch // urls and redirect it to single slash. I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$<br>
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

However it is not working and I see still // in the browser. Is there any issue in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080652/issue-in-removing-double-or-more-slashes-from-url-by-htaccess)