# How to disable open redirect in Nuxt app?

Tags: vue.js, express, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

My app is allowing users to redirect to another websites. If you try https://velas-deploy.herokuapp.com//example.com/ it will be redirected to example.com or any other website you want. Is there any way to disable it?

I'm using Nuxt + i18n.

Comment: What is the use case for this kind of issue ?

Comment: you have an error on your address `//`after .com,

Answer (score 0):

This have nothing to do with Nuxt nor i18n, it is more about server configuration. I even think that this is some default web browser behavior.

Not sure if you can have that kind of change on Heroku, but you can try to look to this kind of configuration: [Issue In Removing Double Or More Slashes From URL By .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080652/issue-in-removing-double-or-more-slashes-from-url-by-htaccess)

But at the end, I'm not sure that you can disable this.