# When I Open Main Domain with http, it Redirect to https with Double Slash at End

Tags: wordpress

When I open the main domain with HTTP  (i.e. http://andsoftwares.com), it redirects to https with a double slash (https://andsoftwares.com//).

However, when I open the main domain with HTTPS (i.e. https://andsoftwares.com), it opens fine without a double slash.

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you using any force to https plugin disable it & try again if not then check your .htaccess file or share the .htaccess RewriteEngine code here

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: This is my .htaccess code

Comment: Your site .htaccess file seems okay. Check if any of these solution works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080652/issue-in-removing-double-or-more-slashes-from-url-by-htaccess.  If not better to contact host 7 ask them to fix this more-ever if can be server side proxy issue!